# Typescript deleting duplicate names from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am fetching data from an api containing a long list of names. Many of them are duplicates and I want to filter the names so there aren't any duplicates.
When trying to run the removeDuplicateNames function it just returns an empty array.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

interface Names {
  objectId: string;
  Name: string;
  Gender: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

function getNames() {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'API.COM',
    headers: {
      'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'xxx',
      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'xxx',
    },
  };

  return axios
    .request(options)
    .then(({ data }: { data: Names[] }) => {
      return data; // Return the retrieved data
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.error(error);
      throw error; // Rethrow the error to propagate it to the caller
    });
}

function removeDuplicateNames(names) {
    return [...new Set(names)];
  }
  

  async function main() {
    const namesFromApi = await getNames();
    const uniqueNames = removeDuplicateNames(namesFromApi);
  
    console.log('Original names:', namesFromApi);
    console.log('Names with duplicates removed:', uniqueNames);
  }
  
  main();
```

The api data looks like this

```json
{
      objectId: '7igkvRJxTV',
      Name: 'Aaron',
      Gender: 'male',
      createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
      updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set wouldn't help you in case when name can be duplicate and other object fields can differ from each other.

The simpliest way is to use `uniqBy` function from `lodash`.

This function creates a duplicate of given array, where duplicates with same property `Name` are removed. Order is guaranteed (would be left only first occurrence).

This library simplifies common operations with collections / objects / etc.

[Reference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy)

```js
import { uniqBy } from  'lodash';

// your code

function removeDuplicateNames(names) {
    return uniqBy(data, 'Name');
  }
```

**Example of output:**

Data:

```json
const data = [{
  objectId: '1',
  Name: 'Aaron',
  Gender: 'male',
  createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
  updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
  },
  {
    objectId: '2',
    Name: 'Aaron',
    Gender: 'male',
    createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
  },
  {
    objectId: '3',
    Name: 'Aaron',
    Gender: 'male',
    createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
  },
  {
    objectId: '3',
    Name: 'Aaron1',
    Gender: 'male',
    createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
  },
];
```

`uniqBy(data, 'Name')` would return

```json
    [
      {
        objectId: '1',
        Name: 'Aaron',
        Gender: 'male',
        createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
        updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
      },
      {
        objectId: '3',
        Name: 'Aaron1',
        Gender: 'male',
        createdAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z',
        updatedAt: '2020-01-23T23:31:10.152Z'
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Does this remove all of the duplicate names or is there a way to keep one of each name?

Comment: @Sindawg it would return array of objects where each object property name is unique.

Comment: @Sindawg added example of output.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the `Set` over objects. If you want to filter duplicates by `Name` key you should:

```js
function removeDuplicateNames(names) {
    const namesOnly = names.map((name) => name.Name);

    return names.filter((name, index) => !namesOnly.includes(name.Name, index+1));
}
```

This way you remove an element from the array only if it has an another occurrence (by `Name` key as an ID) in the array (after its own index).

Answer (score 0):

class `Set` check value equality is based on the [SameValueZero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality) algorithm. You can remove dupulicated JavaScript object items like below:

```
interface User {
  objectid: string;
  name: string;
};  
function removeDuplicateNames(users: User[]): User[] {
  const record: { [string]: boolean } = {};
  const result: User[] = [];
  for (const item of users) {
    if (!record[item.name]) {
      result.push(item);
      recrod[item.name] = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```